# How can I pass a parameter from a Java application to a Cygwin command?

Tags: java, cygwin

Currently I am doing a project in which I need to pass the parameter from the Java application (basically Java Swing) into the Cygwin command interface. How can I do this?

Thanks

Comment: How are you calling cygwin? A bit more detail here would be useful.

Comment: yeah you are right!!!! i should have added little details, i used java .. this is the line that i have used " Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cmd /c start C:\\cygwin\\cygwin.bat"); " i have my cygwin.bat in that above path.

Answer (score 2):

If you look at the contents of `Cygwin.bat`, you'll see it calls the `bash.exe` binary:

```
@echo off

C:
chdir C:\cygwin\bin

bash --login -i
```

Command binaries usually have a `help` argument.  In this case, bash most certainly does:

```
bash --help
GNU bash, version 3.2.49(23)-release-(i686-pc-cygwin)
Usage:  bash [GNU long option] [option] ...
        bash [GNU long option] [option] script-file ...
GNU long options:
        --debug
        --debugger
        --dump-po-strings
        --dump-strings
        --help
        --init-file
        --login
        --noediting
        --noprofile
        --norc
        --posix
        --protected
        --rcfile
        --restricted
        --verbose
        --version
        --wordexp
Shell options:
        -irsD or -c command or -O shopt_option          (invocation only)
        -abefhkmnptuvxBCHP or -o option
Type `bash -c "help set"' for more information about shell options.
Type `bash -c help' for more information about shell builtin commands.
Use the `bashbug' command to report bugs.
```

Now that we know what options it takes, your Java application can call bash directly:

```
String commandString = "help";
Runtime rt = Runtime.getRuntime();
Process pr = rt.exec("C:\\cygwin\\bin\\bash -c " + commandString);
```

Remember to replace `commandString` with the value from your Swing component.

Comment: will u please elaborate this code "Process pr = rt.exec("cygwin-command " + swingValue);
" for instance i want to goto "help" in the cygwin command line interface, so i have to type "help" in the cygwin command prompt, how can i do it with passing the "help" value to the cygwin command prompt via java gui interface. Thanks

Comment: I'm still not completely clear on what you're doing.  I've rewritten my answer to guide you towards pushing commands to cygwin.  You'll have to figure out the specifics yourself or provide more details if I'm off target again.